# Jtable glitch when updating content

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, visual-glitch

My aplication glitches everytime I execute an update of the table model, as one can see in the first picture I make a query with number 1, it returns the data of the resultset in the table, on the picture 2, I do a new query, now with number 2, it seems to work, but when i scroll horizontally the table, the jtable seems to crash and repaint again the first query.

```
public GUIDetalleActividades(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
        setTitle("Detalle Actividades");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 597, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblAContinuacinSe = new JLabel(
                "A continuaci\u00F3n se muestra un listado con todos los proyectos a su cargo,  en el siguiente campo podr\u00E1 consultar");
        lblAContinuacinSe.setBounds(10, 11, 570, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblAContinuacinSe);

        JLabel lblParaVerLos = new JLabel("las actividades de un determinado proyecto");
        lblParaVerLos.setBounds(10, 29, 407, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblParaVerLos);

        //creating upper table with resultset

        table = new JTable(cons.tablaConsultaProyectosACargo(cedula));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setBounds(21, 86, 539, 134);

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JLabel lblConsultarActividadNoproyecto = new JLabel("Consultar actividad No.proyecto:");
        lblConsultarActividadNoproyecto.setBounds(21, 244, 174, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblConsultarActividadNoproyecto);

        txtnum = new JTextField();
        txtnum.setBounds(192, 241, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtnum);
        txtnum.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnConsultar = new JButton("Consultar");
        btnConsultar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //pressing the button should repaint the table with new data and no glitches
                showtable2(txtnum.getText());
            }
        });
        btnConsultar.setBounds(301, 240, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnConsultar);

    }

    //creating table with default table model sent from the class that does all the queries
    public void showtable2(String num) {

        table_1 = new JTable(cons.tablaConsultaActividades(num));
        table_1.setEnabled(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane(table_1, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(20, 310, 552, 134);
        table_1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane_1);
        table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
        table_1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);

        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(table_1);

    }

    public String getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(String cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: *in the first picture* you forgot to post pictures...

Comment: yes sorry uploading it, stackoverflow won't let me to add it manually

Comment: Post links, we can edit them to make them show

Comment: Posted, would apreciate it

Comment: @Frakcool thanks, it looks better now

Comment: I also suggest you to post a [Runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy-paste, which contains the minimum code to reproduce the issue :)

Comment: it would take some issues, :S you know for the database

Comment: Add raw data then... I mean, create a new empty file copy the relevant code there and make it compile and show the "visual glitch" you're seeing in your original app, it will make it easier for us to indentify where the problem might be. Otherwise we should start 1 from scratch and take more time for us to help you. That way you'll get faster and better answers...

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Don't keep recreating the table/scrollpane's.  Instead, make one instance of each and simply update the table's `TableModel`

Comment: @MadProgrammerdo you mean i can instance the table and scrollpanel in the constructor and then it will update when i update table's model?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Solved my problem doing your sugestion, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was in the void showtable2, never re-create the scrollpanel's field or the table model, just delcare them once and update table's model with table.setmodel